# Parsing takes time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, parsing, object

I have a list of class Objects in c#. Class has the properties :

```
int id;
int parentId;
```

*id* is the id of current object and parentId is the id of parent.

now I have more than 100 objects in a list.
I want parse these objects and produce a result in the format (like tree structure)

**first - second - third - fourth**

where each of these are levels

For eg: If we have 8 objects {1,0},{2,1},{3,1},{4,3},{5,3},{6,2},{7,1},{8,4}
result should be:

**first - second - third - fourth**

1   --  --   --

1   2   --   --

1   2   6    --

1   3   --   --

1   3   5    --

1   3   4    --

1   3   4    8

1   7   --   --

Currently what i am doing is using 4 `for loops` as,

```
@for(var item in Model ){
    for(var second in Model ){
         if(second.parentId == item.id){
                //add to table
         }
         for(var third in Model ){
               if(third .parentId == item.id){
                //add to table
               }
               for(var fourth in Model ){

                      if(fourth .parentId == item.id){
                            //add to table
                       }
               }
          }
    }

}
```

Here things will work fine, but its taking too much time to parse as i have 100+ objects in the list(complexity of n^4).

Is there any alternative way to achieve the same?

Comment: That does not really look like a ' tree structure' so not sure exactly how you want to structure the data, but you can use a `.GroupBy(x => x.parentId)` (or `.ToLookup()`) to simplify this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to arrange the data in a way that allows for child IDs to be efficiently accessed for a parent ID. This can be done in constant time by scanning through the list of inputs, and storing the results into a dictionary that maps from parentID to a list of child IDs. Conveniently, Linq provides the .ToLookup extension method that pretty much does that, and presumably in a cost that is roughly O(N).

The root node can either be supplied, or scanned for in constant time. (There may actually be more than one. For that matter, the data may contain cycles).

Then recursively walk the tree, which can be done in O(N) time if there are no cycles.

Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    class Link
    {
        public int id;
        public int parentId;
    }


    static List<Link> GetInput()
    {
        var data = new Dictionary<int, int> {{1,0},{2,1},{3,1},{4,3},{5,3},{6,2},{7,1},{8,4}};
        return data.Select(pair => new Link { id = pair.Key, parentId = pair.Value }).ToList();     
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Link> inputData = GetInput();

        // Scan the nodes and arrange as a lookup (dictionary that maps from parentId to child ids)
        ILookup<int, int> nodes = inputData.ToLookup( link => link.parentId, link => link.id );

        // Find root node(s)
        // (ints that appear as parent IDs, but as child id)
        IEnumerable<int> roots = inputData
            .Select( link => link.parentId)
            .Except( inputData.Select( link => link.id ) );

        foreach (int rootId in roots)
        {
            Display(rootId, nodes, "", 3);
        }       
    }

    static void Display(int id, ILookup<int, int> nodes, string prefix, int padding)
    {
        // Write node to console
        Console.Write(prefix);
        Console.Write(id);
        for (int i=0; i<padding; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(" --");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Recursively write children to console
        string newPrefix = prefix + id.ToString() + " ";
        foreach (int childId in nodes[id])
        {
            Display( childId, nodes, newPrefix, padding-1 );        
        }
    }   
}
```

There's probably lots of things that can be improved about this, but it'll do the job.